# Installing Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, macbook, boot-camp, windows-installation

I have a MacBook Air Mid-2012, I have OSX Yosemite Beta and Windows 8.1 (via BootCamp) installed. I have rEFInd installed too. I would like to install Windows 10 Tech Preview on my MacBook along side of OSX and Windows 8.1, just so I can test out the new OS and make sure all my applications are compatible. Does anyone have any experience with this? Is it just as simple as creating a new partition and running the Windows 10 installer? I have been searching online for the past hour, and I could not find anything of triple booting OSX, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. Everything online is mostly triple booting OSX, Windows, and Ubuntu...

Please note: Running Windows 10 on a VM is not good, as I need the performance.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: It should be the same. The installer for Windows hasn't changed much since the Vista days

Comment: http://huguesval.com/blog/2012/02/installing-windows-7-on-a-mac-without-superdrive-with-virtualbox/